# how to compress the output of cat command

Tags: bash, shell

The title is not good at all, but here is an example of the result of cat :

```
/var/oracle/oradata/DB11G/system01.dbf
/var/oracle/oradata/DB11G/sysaux01.dbf
/var/oracle/oradata/DB11G/undotbs01.dbf
/var/oracle/oradata/DB11G/users01.dbf
/var/oracle/oradata/DB11G/example01.dbf
/var/oracle/oradata/jabba/jabba01.dbf
/var/oracle/oradata/DB11G/control01.ctl
/var/oracle/flash_recovery_area/DB11G/control02.ctl
/var/oracle/oradata/DB11G/redo03.log
/var/oracle/oradata/DB11G/redo02.log
/var/oracle/oradata/DB11G/redo01.log
```

The cat command gives the path to this files

I need to compress this files into a tar.gz

How can i do it?

Comment: You have a list of files in a text file and you want to create a tar.gz archive out of all of those files?

Comment: `tar` has a `--file-from` option: "get names to extract or create from file F"

Comment: Which operating system? On Linux with GNU tar it's easy, with Solaris it's a bit harder.

Comment: Yes, it's a text file which contains the list of files and i want to create a tar.gz with those files. The OS is Ubuntu

Comment: @Ulrich Schwarz it's `--files-from`, note it's plural not singular as you presented.  Also while available in GNU tar, it's not available in BSD tar although BSD tar does have a way to read from a _file_, it's: `−T filename`.

Comment: Do you have the POSIX-specified archiver, `pax`? (Unlike `tar`, any copy of `pax` is guaranteed to be able to read a list of filenames from a stream without relying on vendor extensions... and it can write `tar`-compatible archives).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

As a simple workaround, if your version of tar does not support `--files-from` option, you can use `tr` to produce a command line of files.

Given:

```
$ cat files.txt
/var/oracle/oradata/DB11G/system01.dbf
/var/oracle/oradata/DB11G/sysaux01.dbf
/var/oracle/oradata/DB11G/undotbs01.dbf
/var/oracle/oradata/DB11G/users01.dbf
/var/oracle/oradata/DB11G/example01.dbf
/var/oracle/oradata/jabba/jabba01.dbf
/var/oracle/oradata/DB11G/control01.ctl
/var/oracle/flash_recovery_area/DB11G/control02.ctl
/var/oracle/oradata/DB11G/redo03.log
/var/oracle/oradata/DB11G/redo02.log
/var/oracle/oradata/DB11G/redo01.log
```

You can do:

```
$ cat files.txt | tr '\n' ' '
/var/oracle/oradata/DB11G/system01.dbf /var/oracle/oradata/DB11G/sysaux01.dbf /var/oracle/oradata/DB11G/undotbs01.dbf /var/oracle/oradata/DB11G/users01.dbf /var/oracle/oradata/DB11G/example01.dbf /var/oracle/oradata/jabba/jabba01.dbf /var/oracle/oradata/DB11G/control01.ctl /var/oracle/flash_recovery_area/DB11G/control02.ctl /var/oracle/oradata/DB11G/redo03.log /var/oracle/oradata/DB11G/redo02.log /var/oracle/oradata/DB11G/redo01.log
```

Then use that on the command line of tar.

Most tar implementations (I believe) will also not choke on `\n` in the list of files, so you can do this directly:

```
$ tar -c $(cat files.txt)
```

Or try:

```
$ tar -c $(cat files.txt | tr '\n' ' ')
```

Of course if your tar supports `--files-from`, use that.

Comment: It's `--files-from`, note it's plural not singular as you presented.

Comment: @user3439894: Thanks! My tar does not have it.

Comment: `$(cat files)` string-splits contents -- meaning every space and tab makes content past it a separate argument to `tar`. Being unable to archive filenames with spaces... seriously?

Comment: Also, what if someone creates a file named `./tmp/ /etc/passwd /etc/shadow` (directory names with spaces in them) -- can they force `/etc/shadow` to be archived? :)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Of course you are correct. Needs quotes like I needed a cup o joe before I wrote it...